# Simple Facebook connection with my web site

Tags: php, facebook, user-interface, x-facebook-platform

In one of my web page I need to show the username , well this is a public chat page.
My requirement is if that user is logined in facebook then need to show his name and profile pic other wise prompt for entering new username ?

Any facebook plugin available for this ?

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#personalization

Part of the example they show:

```
FB.api('/me', function(user) {
        if (user) {
          var image = document.getElementById('image');
          image.src = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + user.id + '/picture';
          var name = document.getElementById('name');
          name.innerHTML = user.name
        }
      });
```

I believe the only way you can get this info is by having Facebook login.